# PostgreSQL : 'psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory' .s.PGSQL.5432

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu, unix, psql

Since yesterday I have an error when I run psql on Ubuntu 20.04 - PostgreSQL 12.
Here's the error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have already seen plenty of answers to this question on the internet but no one have worked...

It happened when I restarted postgresql after installing phppgadmin, here are the latest logs :

```
2021-01-01 21:37:27.981 UTC [1071608] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-01-01 21:37:27.982 UTC [1071608] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2021-01-01 21:37:27.982 UTC [434049] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.982 UTC [1514704] thegabdoosan@ephedia_web FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.984 UTC [1231171] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.986 UTC [1231170] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.988 UTC [899543] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.990 UTC [899542] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.992 UTC [899541] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.994 UTC [899540] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.996 UTC [899539] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.998 UTC [899538] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:27.999 UTC [899537] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:28.001 UTC [899536] thegabdoosan@ephedia FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2021-01-01 21:37:28.009 UTC [1071608] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1071615) exited with exit code 1
2021-01-01 21:37:28.010 UTC [1071610] LOG:  shutting down
2021-01-01 21:37:28.030 UTC [1071608] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I don't see anything weird

- pg_hba.conf :

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.106/24        md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

- postgresql.conf

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'                  # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of directories
```

When I try running `psql -h localhost` I have another error :

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When I run `sudo systemctl status postgresql` :

```
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-01-02 09:10:59 UTC; 18min ago
    Process: 1750585 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1750585 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

janv. 02 09:10:59 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
janv. 02 09:10:59 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

When I run `ls /var/run/postgresql/ -a` :

```
0 drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres postgres   80 janv.  1 22:53 .
0 drwxr-xr-x 32 root     root     1060 janv.  2 09:09 ..
0 drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres   40 janv.  1 21:37 12-main.pg_stat_tmp
0 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     postgres   18 janv.  1 22:53 .s.PGSQL.5432 -> /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

When I run `sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start` :

```
Job for postgresql@12-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and `pg_lsclusters` :

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner     Data directory              Log file
12  main    5432 down   <unknown> /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

When I run `sudo systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service` :

```
● postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sat 2021-01-02 13:21:05 UTC; 3h 50min ago
    Process: 705 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 12-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 02 13:21:04 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main...
Jan 02 13:21:05 vps-d989390a postgresql@12-main[723]: Error: Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
Jan 02 13:21:05 vps-d989390a postgresql@12-main[705]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12>
Jan 02 13:21:05 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Jan 02 13:21:05 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: postgresql@12-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Jan 02 13:21:05 vps-d989390a systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main.
```

and here's the last 35 lines of `sudo journalctl -xe` when I run `sudo systemctl start postgresql@12-main.service` :
https://mystb.in/TillDimensionIntellectual.yaml

/etc/init.d/postgresql output : https://mystb.in/AmountsAlexanderExtreme.bash

I've also turned off ufw

If I unintall - install postgresql, will I lose my databases ?

Comment: What does `systemctl status postgresql@12-main.service` show? As well `journalctl -xe` after you attempt the start? Add this information to your question.

Comment: I added it ! 

Comment: Looks to be some combination of permissions error(`Could not open logfile /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log`) and wrong directory(`Can't open PID file /run/postgresql/12-main.pid`). The last should be `/var/run/postgresql/12-main.pid`. How did you install the packages? Do you have more then one type of install on machine?

Comment: I installed the pakages with apt-get. And I think I don't have more than one type of install on the machine :/
If it's a permissions error, can't I fix it with (a) command line(s) ?

Comment: Hmm this `.s.PGSQL.5432 -> /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` is wrong also. I would start by uninstalling `phppgadmin`, since that is when your problems started.

Comment: I already uninstalled it by running `sudo apt-get remove --purge phppgadmin` but nothing changed.

Comment: What are the contents of  `/etc/init.d/postgresql`?

Comment: Also check the permissions on `/etc/postgresql` and `/var/lib/postgresql/`. The cluster `12` and all files below it should be `postgres.postgres`.

Comment: `ls /etc/init.d/postgresql` returns `/etc/init.d/postgresql` (https://imgur.com/02Y4jDm.png)

Comment: I checked and all permissions are postgres.postgres

Comment: I wanted the contents(what is in) of `/etc/init.d/postgresql`.

Comment: How can I get the content ? When I use `ls` I get this : https://imgur.com/02Y4jDm.png

Comment: `vi /etc/init.d/postgresql` will use the VIM text editor to open the file. You can copy and paste from there. Other option is `cat /etc/init.d/postgresql` which will output to screen.

Comment: I have this : https://mystb.in/AmountsAlexanderExtreme.bash

Comment: At this point I don't know what is going on. I will run through all the above again and see if I can pick up something I may have missed before. It may be a little while before I get back to this.

Comment: Just one last question, I have a database that I shouldn't lose and wanted to know if it will be deleted if I uninstall and then reinstall postgresql.

Comment: Fom the log messages ist is obvious that the server did not start because it could not access some directories (for log, maybe the unix-domain socket) Try to create these manually, and give them the correct mode and owner. And try again.

Comment: What are the permissions for `/var/log/postgresql` and `/var/run/postgresql`?  If you are thinking of reinstalling(which I would not do just yet) copy `/var/lib/postgresql/12/main/` somewhere. It contains the data directories for the server.

Comment: `/var/log/postgresql` : https://imgur.com/B0qSQbk.png (The owner seems to be "ubuntu", the default non-root user for OVH) - 
`/var/run/postgresql` : https://imgur.com/82T8JVY.png

Comment: Should I change the owner to postgres ? How ?

Answer (score 1):

The location (or handling) of the lockfile seems to have changed (between versions?). I fixed it by editing the startupfile (which is executed setuid root):
`sudo vi /etc/init.d/postgresql`

---

```
# Parse command line parameters.

case $1 in
  start)
        echo -n "Starting PostgreSQL: "
        test x"$OOM_ADJ" != x && echo "$OOM_ADJ" > /proc/self/oom_adj

        #################################
        # FIX: Directory Lockfile must be writable by postgres
        mkdir -p /var/run/postgresql
        chown postgres.postgres /var/run/postgresql
        ##################################

        #echo su - $PGUSER -c "$DAEMON -D '$PGDATA' &"
        su - $PGUSER -c "$DAEMON -D '$PGDATA' &" >>$PGLOG 2>&1
        echo "ok"
        ;;
  stop)
```

---

BTW: the unix-domain-socket lives in that directory too, sometimes. (used to be `/tmp/` )

BTW2: I put it in the startup script because the `/var/run/` appears to get wiped at reboot.

BTW3: use at your own risk!

Comment: Pretty sure this is not it. I have the same setup as @TheGabDooSan and I can get Postgres 12 to start. Also the above is not the `postgresql` init file that ships with the Ubuntu packages.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That is correct. This is an older version. (I install from source)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not how @TheGabDooSan setup is and so does not apply.